How to type hint a class variable in this situation?
I have the following hierarchy of functionality:
class Formatter:

    def format(self, input):
        ...

class FormatterValidator(Formatter):

    def validate(self, input):
        ...

class FormatterLogger(Formatter):

    def log(self, input):
        ...

...and the following hierarch of users:
class BasicUser:

    def __init__(self, formatterClass):
        self.formatter = formatterClass()

    def doThings(self, input):
        self.formatter.format(input)

class ValidatorUser(BasicUser):

    def __init__(self):
        BasicUser.__init__(FormatterValidator)

    def doStuff(self, input):
        self.formatter.format(input)

    def doOtherStuff(self, input):
        self.formatter.validate(val)

class LoggerUser(BasicUser):

    def __init__(self):
        BasicUser.__init__(FormatterLogger)

    def foo(self, input):
        self.formatter.format(input)

    def bar(self, input)
        self.formatter.log(val)

The question is how to typehint the formatterClass parameter in BasicUser? If I typehint it as formatterClass: Type[Formatter], the type checker complains on rows such as ValidatorUser.doStuff where the error is "self.formatter doesn't have a validate() method". If I annotate it as formatterClass: Type[Union[FormatterValidator, FormattedLogger]] the type checker will complain in ValidatorUser that self.formatter doesn't necessarily have the method validate(), and the inverse is true for LoggerUser who doesn't necessarily have the method log().
So how do I typehint the formatterClass so that no part of the code will have complaints?

You should make Formatter an abstract base class, with an abstract method do_thing, which FormatterValidator and FormatterLogger implement

@TomMcLean I don't see how an abstract base class will help me here. The problem is that the children of Formatter have additional methods. I realize that my example made it look like I can get by with one do_thing() method, but a format() and validate() method will not necessarily be used in conjunction. Updated the example.

From your edits it still looks like you could use an abstract base class

@TomMcLean To use an abstract base class I will have to stick validate() and log() in there as abstract methods. I will not be able to use "just" the base Formatter in BasicUser because now the unimplemented abstract method prevent it from being instantiated, and also the existence of these methods in the base class implies knowledge of possible subclasses. I don't want to add a new abstract method to the base class each time I want to create a new subclass.

You can rename validate and log though to the same name

Use an abstract base class
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Formatter(ABC):

    def format(self, format_input):
        print(f"Formatting {format_input}")

    @abstractmethod
    def do_stuff(self, to_input):
        pass


class FormatterValidator(Formatter):

    def do_stuff(self, to_input):
        print(f"Format validator doing stuff")


class FormatterLogger(Formatter):

    def do_stuff(self, to_input):
        print(f"Format logger doing stuff")


class BasicUser:

    def __init__(self, formatter_class: Formatter):
        self.formatter = formatter_class

    def do_things(self, in_input):
        self.formatter.do_stuff(in_input)


class ValidatorUser(BasicUser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(FormatterValidator())

    def do_stuff(self, in_input):
        self.formatter.format(in_input)

    def do_other_stuff(self, in_input):
        self.formatter.do_stuff(in_input)


class LoggerUser(BasicUser):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(FormatterLogger())
    
    def foo(self, in_input):
        self.formatter.format(in_input)
    
    def bar(self, in_input):
        self.formatter.do_stuff(in_input)

If you cannot change the structure of the code, you can do this:
class ValidatorUser(BasicUser):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(FormatterValidator)
        self.formatter: FormatterValidator

    def doStuff(self, input):
        self.formatter.format(input)

    def doOtherStuff(self, input):
        self.formatter.validate(input)

class LoggerUser(BasicUser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(FormatterLogger)
        self.formatter: FormatterLogger

    def foo(self, input):
        self.formatter.format(input)

    def bar(self, input):
        self.formatter.log(input)


Unfortunately I really have to keep the very specific structure I defined in the question. Formatter has to be instantiable on its own, so it can't have any abstract methods, and it shouldn't make assumptions about how many new methods subclasses may add to it. An answer to my question could well be that Python's type system cannot represent such a design, that's the conclusion I'm starting to arrive to, but I was hoping I might have missed something.

@Primordial_Hamster I have modified my answer, but I am 99.9% sure your code should be implemented with abstract base classes

BasicUser should be generic in the formatter type:
class BasicUser[FC: FormatterClass]:

    def __init__(self, formatterClass: FC):
        self.formatter = formatterClass()

    def doThings(self, input):
        self.formatter.format(input)

and the subclasses should inherit from specializations of BaseUser:
class ValidatorUser(BasicUser[FormatterValidator]):
    def doStuff(self, input):
        self.formatter.format(input)

    def doOtherStuff(self, input):
        self.formatter.validate(val)


class LoggerUser(BasicUser[FormatterLogger]):    
    def foo(self, input):
        self.formatter.format(input)

    def bar(self, input)
        self.formatter.log(val)

Note there is no need to override __init__: the body is the same, but inheriting from a specialized version means that the subclass __init__ methods are correspondingly specialized.
